# Cannot see Routes when mounting Rails 3 Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I have created a Rails Engine (as per the [Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)) using:

```
rails plugin new address_book --full --mountable
```

I proceeded to create a controller for the Engine called `pages` with a single action (called `temp`) to display a single view, namely `app/views/address_book/pages/temp.html.erb`

The Engine's config/routes.rb is:

```
AddressBook::Engine.routes.draw do
  match :temp, to: "pages#temp" 
end
```

In the parent application I added the following in it's routes.rb file:

```
mount AddressBook::Engine => "/address_book", as: "address_book"
```

In an action of one of the parent application's controllers I have the following call to a view belonging to the Engine:

```
redirect_to address_book.temp_path
```

Now, even though `rake routes` displays the Engine's path, when I try to execute the action from the browser I keep getting the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `address_book'
```

for the line `redirect_to address_book.temp_path`

The result of rake routes contains the following:

```
address_book        /address_book         AddressBook::Engine

Routes for AddressBook::Engine:
temp  /temp(.:format) address_book/pages#temp
```

I cannot seem to understand what I'm missing, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long process of trial and error (and shutting down the PC for the night) I realised that all I needed to do was **restart the server**

Hope this post help others with the same stumbling block.